# iPhone 3GS Simulator

Tags: iphone, macos, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator

I want to test the Voice Control feature of iPhone 3GS through the simulator. But I don't seem to get the simulator for 3GS. Where can I get one..?

Comment: Voice Control is not a feature available to applications via the SDK. It is a builtin application that only works with the builtin application. It is not available in the simulator because it does not effect anything you can do in any app you write.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Voice Control is not simulated. Neither is GPS, the compass or the camera. I'm afraid you have to ressort to on device debugging.

Comment: GPS is simulated, isn't it? It always returns the same coordinates with a horizontal accuracy of a 100 meters...

Answer (score 0):

But I came across some images of simulator which had some 3GS settings in the Settings application.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simulator you saw was a website meant for people who want to explore the iPhone interface (and iPhone support agents). There are several such simulators available for this purpose and they are being updated for 3.0/3GS features.

These, however, are not true simulators like the iPhone Simulator app on OS X and you cannot really interact with them. They're generally interactive image slideshows or PDFs.